# Convert a list to individual cells in Excel

Tags: excel

How can I convert this list into individual cells into excel without the columns?

```
     AL,AZ,CA,CO,CT,DE,FL,GA,HI,IA,ID,IL,IN,KS,KY,MA,MD,ME,MI,MN,MO,MT,NC,NE,NH,NJ,NM,NV,NY,OH,OK,OR,PA,RI,SC,TN,TX,UT,VA,WA,WI
```

Comment: You can use Text to Columns for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is just the "Text to Columns" option under the Data ribbon.

Edit: Thanks to Jeeped for this, you can copy the resulting cells and paste special, using the transposed option to get the data into rows instead of columns.

Comment: Following up with *Copy, Paste Special, Values, Transpose* may be necessary depending upon what the OP meant by *without the columns*,

Comment: Hi, I did try transpose and it did not work, I think transpose only works if a list is vertical and you want it horizontal? I also tried text to columns, but I'll play with it some more because I also thought that should work.

Comment: @SQUISH You have to do the text to columns first, then you can select all of the cells that were created and copy that and to do the paste transpose. Trust me I tried it out, it works.

Answer (score 1):

In excel, a return character is kind of treated like a "go to next row and write what comes after the return character there."

So if you have `AL,AZ,CA,` and you just go into notepad and replace the commas with enter so it looks like this:

```
AL
AZ
CA
```

and then you copy paste that into excel, it will put each state into its own row.